# industry standard solutions to email verification as part of login process?

Tags: email-validation

I'm looking for an industry proven method to verify a users email as part of a login process.

That is, the user logs into a site (using email and password) and if valid, the system auto-generates an email to that address for the user to click on within a 30 minute time window to complete the log in process.

My language preference to implement this would be (listed in order of preference): Flex/ActionScript, HTML, Java, or PhP.

Are there any proven routines that can be "dropped" into an application that take care of this?

Comment: *(not really an asnwer hence the comment but...)* every single open source forum offer this functionality.  On the Java side of things you could take JForum and see how they're doing it.  Note that OpenID is getting more and more common to authenticate seen that nearly everyone has Google / Yahoo / etc.  It's good to typically offer both choices: for example SourceForge allows you to generate an account either the "old way" (the one you describe) or by using OpenID.

Comment: In my case I don't think OpenID would work because I actually need to verify the user is a member at the email domain name they provide. For example, if you register with an email joe.smith@companyA.com, I need to make sure you actually have a valid email address at companyA, because my website has a business relationship with companyA to provide them certain benefits, etc.

Comment: indeed... Now that said: OpenID now works for "Google Apps for business/domain" and you can get the email of the person using OpenID auth but you're right: most domains aren't using Google Apps :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know whether they are industry proven or not but works for me.

Two ways:

1. At the time of registeration, add a very long unique string in column 'verify' in your database along with other fields like 'username', 'password (hash)' etc. 
   Now, send a link of your website's page (e.g. verify.jsp) to the mentioned email with that unique no and his email as querystring.

   xyz.com?verify.jsp?str= &email=

Now, on verify.jsp , check if str and email values exits in database. It then change them to 1 (verified).

Now at login, check if verify column is 1 or not.

1. Dont give user a way to choose their password at registeration. Send a temporary password to their email address. They can only sign in when they have password. Give them option to change password on first sign in.

I recommend 1st way and I have seen it on many websites.